# J-2 rocket nozzle length

Tags: nozzle, j-2, dimensions

The total length of the J-2 rocket engine is 133 inches, but what is its nozzle length from throat to exit?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Space_Engines/SP-8120_Excerpt.pdf) (which I [found here](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Space_Engines/Rocketdyne_Engines.htm)) says 90 inches **throat** to exit. Two other items below show **gimbal center** to exit of 116 inches. So far I can not find the relationship between the throat and the gimbal center.

[image]

**above:** **Throat** to exit - 90 inches. found [here](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Space_Engines/Rocketdyne_Engines.htm).

[image]

**above:** **Gimbal center** to exit - 116 inches. See the "J-2S Side Drawing" [link here](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Space_Engines/Rocketdyne_Engines.htm).

[image]

**above:** **Gimbal center** to exit - 116 inches. See the "J-2 vs J-2S, McDonnell Phase B Shuttle Study" [link here](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Space_Engines/Rocketdyne_Engines.htm).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here are J2-S numbers.

The paper "[Altitude Developmental Testing of the J2-S](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/874400.pdf)" gives the throat diameter as 12.192 inches and the expansion ratio as 39.62.

Paragraph 2.1.1

> Thrust Chamber — The tubular-walled, bell-shaped thrust chamber
>   consists of an 18.6-in.-diam combustion chamber with a throat diameter
>   of 12.192 in., a characteristic length (L*) of 35.4, and a divergent
>   nozzle with an expansion ratio of 39.62. **Thrust chamber length (from
>   the injector flange to the nozzle exit) is 108.6 in.** Cooling is
>   accomplished by the circulation of engine fuel flow downward from the
>   fuel manifold through 180 tubes and then upward through 360 tubes to
>   the injector and by film cooling inside the combustion chamber.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Please feel free to clarify or reject the material I've just added, or use it in any way to improve your answer. I'm a fish out of water when it comes to engine design. The goal would be to assemble one definitive answer.