# F1 engine specification?

Tags: rockets, engines, nozzle, specifications

I am collecting the engine specification data of different engines.
I want to know the nozzle length and combustion chamber length and diameter of the F1 engine of Saturn-5.

Please give some reference for the specification of the engine.

If you have reference for any other engines, or can offer advice on search strategies, please share that too.

Thank you

Comment: Check out the references at the bottom of the [wikipedia page on the F-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1); in particular, #4 "Saturn V News Reference: F-1 Engine Fact Sheet"

Comment: Don't forget to search the site for existing answers! For example you might find [J-2 rocket nozzle length](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20091/12102) as well as [What are the differences between a standard Merlin engine and the Merlin Vacuum engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8806/12102) helpful.

Comment: Okay, I'll take care from next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The brilliant and original  [F-1 Engine Familiarization Manual](http://agentdc.uah.edu/homepages/dcfiles/USSRC/F1EngiFamiTraiManu%20Section%201_072308152849.pdf) is a good place to start looking, also for sizes. I'm travelling now; as soon as I'm back (a few days) I can add info from other, offline docs.

Comment: Link didn't work for me. This one did: http://web.archive.org/web/20150509173846/http://agentdc.uah.edu/homepages/dcfiles/USSRC/F1EngiFamiTraiManu%20Section%201_072308152849.pdf